# DTD error while validating

Tags: xml, dtd, uniface

I am new to DTDs and there is this error that I get while validating one of the DTDs. The error says : "DTD erro, Element 'EQR_CA_ADD-BASIS_DATE" is referenced previously, but not defined.

Comment: It's saying the element `EQR_CA_ADD-BASIS_DATE` is referenced in an element declaration, but it's not defined/declared anywhere. You need to declare it (`<!ELEMENT EQR_CA_ADD-BASIS_DATE ...>`).

Comment: Now I am getting the same error, but there is no element name mentioned. It simply says : DTD error, Element '' is referenced previously, but not defined.

Comment: If you add your DTD to your question, I can take a look.